# c++ "error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’"

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ programming and I've been getting an error that I can't seem to figure out.  I've tried it many different ways and just get variations of the same error.  here is the error and my code:

```
 account.cxx: In member function ‘char* account::get_name() const’:                                                                                                                                                                     
 account.cxx:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ 

          //File: account.h
 68     class account
 69     {
 70     public:
 71     typedef char* string;
 72     static const size_t MAX_NAME_SIZE = 15;
 73         // CONSTRUCTOR
 74     account (char* i_name, size_t i_acnum, size_t i_hsize);
 75     account (const account& ac);
 76     // DESTRUCTOR
 77     ~account ( );
 78         // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
 79     void set_name(char* new_name);
 80     void set_account_number(size_t new_acnum);
 81     void set_balance(double new_balance);
 82     void add_history(char* new_history);
 83     // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
 84     char* get_name ( ) const;
 85         size_t get_account_number ( ) const;
 86         double get_balance( ) const;
 87     size_t get_max_history_size( ) const;
 88         size_t get_current_history_size ( ) const;
 89         string* get_history( ) const;
 90         friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const account& target);
 91     private:
 92     char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]; //name of the account holder
 93     size_t ac_number; //account number
 94     double balance; //current account balance
 95     string *history; //Array to store history of transactions
 96     size_t history_size; //Maximum size of transaction history
 97     size_t history_count; //Current size of transaction history
 98     };


 1 // File: account.cxx
 2 // Author: Mike Travis
 3 // Last Modified: Feb, 26, 2012
 4 // Description: implementation of Account class as prescribed by the file account.h
 5 
 6 #include <stdio.h>
 7 #include <iostream>
 8 #include "account.h"
 9 
 10 using namespace std;
 11 //Constructor
 12 
 13 account::account(char* i_name, size_t i_acnum, size_t i_hsize){
 14 string *d_history = NULL;
 15 d_history = new string[i_hsize];
 16 
 17 for(int i = 0; i<MAX_NAME_SIZE +1; i++){
 18     name[i] = i_name[i];
 19 }
 20 ac_number = i_acnum;
 21 history_size = i_hsize;
 22 history_count = 0;
 23 }
 24 
 25 char* account::get_name() const {
 26 return &name;
 27 }
```

I haven't yet written the rest of the implementation file since I can't get around this error.

In line 26 of account.cxx I have tried several variations with no success.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: Is that the **exact** error message for that **exact** code? (Hint: no). The type of `&name` in `account::get_name()` is `char (*)[MAX_NAME+1]` not `char*`, and the compiler should be able to tell you that much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare `get_name() const`, which means that `this` is a `const` pointer. By extension, `name` is also `const`, and can only be converted to `const char*`. You should `return name`, not `return &name`—`&name` is a *pointer to an array*, not an array. Array names are implicitly convertible to element pointers; pointers to arrays are not.

Apart from that, you need only change the declaration to the following:

```
const char* get_name() const;
```

Or the mutable equivalent:

```
char* get_name();
```

However, if you’re using C++, use C++ features: there is a `std::string` class for a reason, and it will save you a lot of trouble in the long run over using C-style strings:

```
string get_name() const;
```

You’re already using `string` for `history`, after all. Also, you might change `string* history` to `vector<string> history`, using the `std::vector` class from the `<vector>` header. This will hide the details of memory management involved in adding and removing history items.

Comment: the header file (with the strage indentation) was given to us by our professor.  We aren't supposed to change it at all, just write the implementation file for it.  Jon, your correction will work, but is there a way to do this without any changes to the header file account.h?

Comment: @user1238900: If you need a horrific hack to get around the horrific code, use `const_cast<char*>(name)`, which (unsafely) removes the `const` qualifier from the pointer. But you can also use this as an opportunity to learn from your professor’s mistakes. ;)

Comment: A professor who enforces a bad implementation instead of letting you figure out your own? I wouldn't take any more of their classes.

Comment: @AJG85: Welcome to almost every CS class I’ve ever heard of. I’ve tutored CS students through years of this kind of crap. Professors are averse to libraries because they want their students to learn the hard way; to modern, good-quality code, because they think C++ and C are the same language; and to fully personal implementations, because grading is time-consuming. Of course all of these “justifications” ultimately backfire.

Comment: Frustrating isn't it? I said screw it and changed his header file anyway.  The indentation alone was driving me crazy, ha.

anyway, this site kicks ass.  this was my first post and you guys nailed it in minutes.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bummer, I guess I got lucky going to a private college then. My programming professors did not give us any code and when you got to higher level classes you could use whatever language you wanted. By senior year I only had one class which wasn't created and run by students.

Comment: This is **wrong**: *`&name` (or equivalently just `name`) has the type `const char*`*. Given a variable `t` of type `T` that does not override `operator&`, the expression `t` and `&t` don't have the same type. In this particular case (and ignoring the `const` in the signature), `name` has type `char [MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]` (which can be implicitly converted to `char *`) and `&name` has type `char (*)[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]` which **cannot** be converted to `char*` (BTW, this is actually a good example to demonstrate that *arrays and pointers are not the same*)

Comment: @Mtravis: BTW, if you really want to piss off your instructor change the signature of the function to: `char const (&get_name() const)[ MAX_NAME_SIZE+1 ];`... (before you do that, understand what it means)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That’s right. Mea culpa. The OP’s error was “invalid conversion from ‘`const char*`’ to ‘`char*`’”, so that’s what I addressed, but my answer is incomplete. Will edit to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* account::get_name() const
```

should be

```
const char* account::get_name() const
```

If that error wasn't stopping you, people could start editing your object's name!

Answer (score 0):

`account::get_name()` is a `const` member function, which means that its access to any data member is also `const`. That means it sees `name` as a `char const[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]`.

Also:

- `&name` is a `char const(*)[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]`
- `name` — when it decays — will turn into a `char const*`, and that's what you want.

So:

```
const char* account::get_name() const
{
   return name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1];
```

... is `const char * ()[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1]` not `char *`. Try using *std::string*.

Comment: No, it's not "equal" to that at all. It certainly has nothing to do with function types.